# How to save a model in sails.js?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, sails.js

How to save this model Items in sails.js

```
 module.exports = {
 attributes: {
     name : {
         en: {type: String},            
         fr: {type: String},
         it: {type: String},
         es: {type: String}
     }
 }
};
```

i tried to do like this
In controller

```
 module.exports = {       
  addItem: function(req, res) {      
 var params = {
      en : req.body.en,
      fr : req.body.fr,
      it : req.body.it,
      es : req.body.es          
  };

    Items.addItem(params, function(success) {
        res.json(success);
    });
}
 };
```

and after this i called a service

```
 module.exports = {
  addItem: function(params, next) {
Items.create({value: params}).exec(function(err, item) {
  if(err) throw err;
  next(item);
});
}
 };
```

But when i try to post an object i get the following error
unknown rule: en
How to solve this? Thanks

Comment: I think it is because `en` must be in `name`

Comment: `en : req.body.en,
fr : req.body.fr,
it : req.body.it,
es : req.body.es` check this things work properly

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do here is embedding sub-document and the problem is that sails waterline do not have support for embedding yet, for now you can check the status of this issue on [git-hub here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/44) as sails team has included this in their feature request and may be introduced in upcoming versions.

If you still want to store it do not declare it in model it will be saved eventually but not recommended.

You can store it as an array too it will help i guess.

Check out #sails-mongo : [How can I validate a Sub-document? git-hub](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/112)